# How do I mocking with Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I'm doing unit testing and **I can't program the Mockito to cover a portion of the code**. 
How do I get Mockito return me something valid? I get an `IllegalArgumentExpection` that code when i get `spec`. Sorry if it's an ignorant question, I started writing tests recently.

My test

```
@Bean
        public SpecDBDAO getSpecDBDAO() {
            SpecDBDAO dao = Mockito.mock(SpecDBDAO.class);
            when(dao.findLastOne(new BasicDBObject("_id", "erro"))).thenReturn(new BasicDBObject());
            return dao;
        }

 @Test
    public void testAddLinha_validId() throws Exception {
        planilhaService.addLinha("123", new BasicDBObject("_id", "erro"));
    }
```

My code

```
public Planilha addLinha(String id, BasicDBObject body) {
        String idSpec = body.getString("_id", "");
        Planilha planilha = specDBPlanilhasDAO.get(id);
        if (planilha == null) {
            throw new NotFoundException("Planilha não encontrada.");
        }

        try {
            BasicDBObject spec = specDBDAO.findLastOne(new BasicDBObject("_id", new ObjectId(idSpec)));
            if (spec.isEmpty()) {
                throw new NotFoundException("Especificação não encontrada.");
            }
            planilha.addLinha(spec);
            planilha = specDBPlanilhasDAO.update(planilha);

            return planilha;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new BadRequestException("Id inválido.");
        }
    }
```

Coverage
[image]

Comment: Never apologise for writing tests!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BasicDBObject` instance you're using here

```
BasicDBObject spec = specDBDAO.findLastOne(new BasicDBObject("_id", new ObjectId(idSpec)));
```

is different to the `BasicDBObject` instance you're using here

```
when(dao.findLastOne(new BasicDBObject("_id", "erro"))).thenReturn(new BasicDBObject());
```

**Solution**

1 Override `equals()` and `hashCode()` on `BasicDBObject` so equality is based on, for example, `id` and `errno` along with any other values that are necessary.

2  Use the org.mockito.Matchers class to give you a matcher when you set up the expectation, for example

```
when(dao.findLastOne(Matchers.any(BasicDBObject.class).thenReturn(new BasicDBObject()); 
// any BasicDBObject instance will trigger the expectation
```

or

```
when(dao.findLastOne(Matchers.eq(new BasicDBObject("_id", "erro")).thenReturn(new BasicDBObject()); 
// any BasicDBObject equal to the used here instance will trigger the expectation.  Equality is given by your overridden equals method
```

You can find more information on this [here](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#3).